# android maven plugin in netbeans

Tags: android, maven, netbeans, android-maven-plugin

I am trying to use android in netbeans with maven as the build tool. I want to be able to run the applications in netbeans and also run the emulator in netbeans itself. So far i have been using the command line for creating android applications with maven. Any help will be appreciated
thanks in advance
Abhirami

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible with stock distribution of NetBeans IDE. Everything Android related will be handled by Maven there (including compilation against correct platform and special goals to deploy).

You will miss some goodies provided [NBAndroid](http://www.nbandroid.org/) for regular Android projects. Some of them are available as you can read at http://www.nbandroid.org/2012/06/did-you-ask-for-maven.html.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to integrate maven with eclipse? 
It's pretty simple. You Just have to follow the instructions [here.](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

for NetBeans - 
"NetBeans includes full Maven support since 6.7, including Maven 3 support in 7.0+. You can open any Maven project in the IDE and start coding immediately." as quoted [here](http://maven.apache.org/netbeans-module.html)